# 500 Internal Server Error in subdomains with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, zend-framework, subdomain

I am running across a situation here.
I have this site http://liuitt.com running Zend with the following .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteRule !\.(js|gif|jpg|png|css|txt|eot|svg|ttf|woff|ico|pdf)$ public/index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [NC,L]
```

I am trying to install FengOffice on a subdomain http://crm.liuitt.com

But the trouble is that I get 500 Internal Server Error.

Then... If I disable the .htaccess in my root folder over liuitt.com it works.

How can I solve this problem?

How can I have a subdomain working with it's very own .htaccess file?

Comment: Try adding an empty .htaccess file to the `crm` directory since it might be defaulting to the one on your main site since Apache will look for htaccess files from the working directory and if it doesn't find one it will keep looking in parent folders until it gets to your document root.

Comment: Yep. There is already a .htaccess file in the crm directory. But it still keeps the error message.

Comment: In that case check the `error_log` file of Apache and see what the cause of the 500 error is.  It should show something as the cause.

Comment: I got this several times in the log file:
_[Thu Jul 12 12:39:10 2012] [error] [client 201.81.33.81] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use LimitInternalRecursion to increase the limit if necessary. Use LogLevel debug to get a backtrace._

Comment: Are there any rewrite rules in the .htaccess file in the crm directory?  Basically you have an infinite loop in one of your rewrite rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.
It's necessary to add the RewriteEngine in the .htaccess file for each subdomain that has a root .htaccess in the main domain rewriting the request to anywhere else.

```
RewriteEngine On
;or Off
```

The above command fixed my problem!

http://liuitt.com and http://crm.liuitt.com are working altogether with no errors.

I've created other subdomains to test it alongside and it's okay too.

Comment: Thanks Google, and thanks to you, I was having the same problem. +1